# Reading writing nfc tags

Tags: android, nfc

I have just start reading and writing nfc tags using google nexus one . I have gone through several site like [this](http://gibraltarsf.com/blog/?p=13). They have mostly given for a single string writing. Is that possible to write more data . For example in my case i have to write person id , place and timings .Is there any example like this ?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can put whatever information you want - there are no limits for that. The only limitation is a space available on particular tag type which is different for different tag types. For the tag compatibility check the documentation, e.g. Nokia supports all NFC forun tags 1-4 + Mifare classic, while Nexus S might have some limitations here (http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.3.html).

You are free to use whatever data format you like to save on the NFC tag - but there are certain standards pushed by NFC Forum - just search internet for for NDEF/RTD terms.

The most widely used NFC tag is currently MIFARE Ultralight, but Broadcom BCM20203 NFC Tag might be option as well, but I am not sure if it is distributed or not.

BR
STeN
www.mautilus.com

Answer (score 0):

I have created an Eclipse [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) for creating NDEF types of NFC payloads you might be interested in.

Also see the [NDEF Tools for Java](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/) project for an Android boilerplate project for detecting, reading and writing NFC tags.